# What is the maximum number of connections?

Tags: rethinkdb

Since the native RethinkDB drivers do not support connection pooling yet, I was wondering, what is the maximum number of connections to the RethinkDB server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple answers to this question:

**Connection Pooling**

There are some third-party drivers that do have connection pooling. [rethinkdbdash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash), for example, is a great Node.js driver that has connection pooling.

**Maximum Number Of Connections**

I'm not sure there's a hard limit on number of connections on the RethinkDB side, but users usually run into the connection limits of the OS before really running into the maximum number of connections on the RethinkDB side (I don't think there is one). Basically, RethinkDB can easily handle thousands of connections without a problem.